# Firebase hosted site says "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

My website was hosted on firebase, It was working fine. But from few days I am getting this error =>

[image]

In the release history, I saw one of my team members deployed a different site there. I again deployed my previous site. But it is still showing me the same error. Now I don't know how to get rid of this problem. Do I need to setup the custom domain again ? Please help!!

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support directly: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks for the help,
Google did replied with a solution, but it didn't work. They told me to contact the DNS provider support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved::::::

First contact https://firebase.google.com/support , then they will definitely suggest you something. In my case they told me to delete the extra IP that was registered and told me to discuss more with my domain provider website's support. My domain provider helped me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the DNS configuration. You need only two IP addresses, but there are three:

```
speakee.jp.     3551    IN  A   157.7.107.57
speakee.jp.     3551    IN  A   151.101.65.195
speakee.jp.     3551    IN  A   151.101.1.195
```

You should delete the first one (`157.7.107.57`) and keep the other two.

Comment: Thanks mate,
Firebase support also replied with the same solution. But I am unable to find the first A record in my DNS configuration. It only contains the last 2 A records. Any more help mate ? 
I am using https://muumuu-domain.com/

Comment: I can't read Japanese, but sometimes there is something enabled, like "_parked site_" or similar (I've seen it on namecheap and godaddy).